# Get worker id from Gunicorn worker itself

Tags: python, webserver, gunicorn, worker

I run multiple gunicorn workers with `workers=4` setting. So as I understand I have 5 different processes: one gunicorn master process and 4 other worker processes. Can I get information about which worker is serving request at the moment? So can I get any worker id from inside worker itself like for each request send back a response with content: **this request was served by worker:worker_id**?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? If yes, can you provide the example.

Comment: @neel, so inside your worker code just simply call `import os; print(os.getpid())`

Comment: @MostWanted Please make this an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For debugging purpose, you may use post_request hook to log the worker pid

```
def post_response(worker, req, environ, resp):
    worker.log.debug("%s", worker.pid)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what we actually do

Comment: How to use it within the python file? How can we print worker id with each request?

Comment: @neel, if you want to make that code working, place the snippet into e.g. `gunicorn_config.py` and then launch your code with `gunicorn app_module:app --config gunicorn_config.py`, so it will pick up this hook and will log the desired info

Comment: The name of the hook is now `post_request` (Gunicorn 20.1.0)

Answer (score 22):

Within a worker code just use

```
import os
print(os.getpid())
```

Process id is a good enough identifier for such a case. Another option which is overkill obviously is to create a worker-id-file for each worker at this point https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=hooks#post-worker-init and read from it when needed. Do not forget to remove this file on exit https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=hooks#worker-exit